# How to convert string [formatted in array] into array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on Api with nodejs and I want to convert string format [10,20] in to array.

for example

//my co worker sent me string

```
employee_id : [ 10, 20 ];
```

and I check

```
if(Array.isArray(employee_id) || employee_id instanceof Array){
}
```

It's not working

andI try to `typeof employee_id;  it's return  string`

How can I change format string to an array

Comment: `JSON.parse(employee_id)`

Answer (score 2):

Parse your result to JSON before comparison.

```
const employees = JSON.parse(employee_id)
if(Array.isArray(employees) {

}
```

It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

> The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

```
if(Array.isArray(JSON.parse(employee_id)) || JSON.parse(employee_id) instanceof Array){
}
```

***Demo:***

```js
var obj = {employee_id : '[ 10, 20 ]'};

console.log(typeof obj.employee_id);//string

if(Array.isArray(JSON.parse(obj.employee_id)) || JSON.parse(employee_id) instanceof Array){
  console.log('array')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

API returns JSON string,
So You have to parse the string to JSON object to check the acutal data type.

```
if(Array.isArray(JSON.parse(employee_id)) || JSON.parse(employee_id) instanceof Array){
}
```